# Get distance between two objects from an ortographic point of view

Tags: unity

I want to be able to measure the distance from one object to another through the camera's orthographic projection.

**As shown here, the objects are away from each other**

[image]

**When I move the camera, they "appear" to be closer together:**

[image]

I want to be able to measure that blue line. How can I make this possible?

Comment: In what space? Do you need the world space distance? Or a view space distance?

Answer (score 6):

Take both object centers and pass them through the `WorldToScreenPoint` or `WorldToViewportPoint` function of your camera then calculate the 2D distance (magnitude of the difference).

```
Vector3 screenPos1 = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(target1.position);
Vector3 screenPos2 = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(target2.position);
float distance = new Vector2(
        screenPos1.x-screenPos2.x, screenPos1.y-screenPos2.y
    ).magnitude;
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToViewportPoint.html

> Viewport space is normalized and relative to the camera. The
>   bottom-left of the camera is (0,0); the top-right is (1,1). The z
>   position is in world units from the camera.

Comment: It works, however, the distance is completely different on the PC screen and on my phone screen (86 on PC, 205 on mobile), and that breaks everything

Comment: Then use WorldToViewportPoint instead. That will give you normalized coordinates rather than pixels.

Answer (score 2):

When we get the normal distance between two game objects, we simply work out the distance based off the 3D coordinates.

When we change to an orthographic view, all we are doing is changing to a *2D* perspective. Distance works *in exactly the same way*, except we work it out based off *2D* coordinates.

We can convert our positions to `Vector2` and use the inbuilt `Vector2.Distance` method, or use Pythagoras's theorem to work it out, manually.

---

### Using `Vector2.Distance`

If we convert the 3D positions to 2D<sup>1</sup>, we can simply use the `Vector2.Distance` method. In context of an *orthographic* view, this means we only really need to ommit the `z` value in our game objects `Vector3` position.

Here is an example of a method that will determine the orthographic distance between two `Vector3` coordinates, and output the value as a `float`.

```
public float GetOrthographicDistance(Vector3 a, Vector3 b)
{
    return Vector2.Distance(
        new Vector2(a.x, a.y), new Vector2(b.x, b.y));
}
```

#### Using Pythagoras's theorem

Pythagoras's theorem tells us that, in an equilateral triangle, the square of the longest side is equal to the sum of the squares of the other two sides.

> a<sup>2</sup> = b<sup>2</sup> + c<sup>2</sup>

Using this theorem, we can easily create a manual method to work out the distance, as follows.

```
public float GetOrthographicDistance(Vector3 vectorA, Vector3 vectorB)
{
    // a^2 = b^2 + c^2

    float b = vectorA.x - vectorB.x;
    float c = vectorA.y - vectorB.y;

    float a = Mathf.Sqrt((b * b)+ (c * c));

    return a;
}
```

---

<sub>1 I have read Unity tutorials that claim you can pass a `Vector3` freely into a `Vector2`, but I can not find an implicit cast overload, nor have I ever seen this actually done.</sub>

Comment: For the last part of the answer you can simply do `Vector2 v2 = someExistingVector3;`

Comment: The first example works, however, the distance is completely different on the PC screen and on my phone screen, and that breaks everything. Also, bitwise exclusive operators can't be used with floats or doubles

Comment: @Gnemlock The distance calculated on a PC screen is totally different than what is calculated on a phone screen, is there a reason for that?

Comment: @Milen, my examples work off *direct positions*. The only way a phone could give a different calculation is if the two game objects are not at the same physical position. Try a test where you directly set each objects transform position prior to calculating, and see if there is still platform inconsistency. Note that this *does* make sense in regards to the accepted answer; a PC likely has a different screen size, which directly alters output of a "screen position".